# Upgrade nxt explorer to draw a map

Tags: nxt, lego-mindstorms

I have made this robot:
http://www.nxtprograms.com/explorer/steps.html#Program
and i want to upgrade it to draw a map of the environment where he moves.

I have tried a lot of things but never succeeded, and also i can not find a good tutorial to make this.

Can you help me and tell me how to do this?

I am using nxt 2.0 and my robot and the code are the same from the link above.